# what is the degree of ionization of glow discharge tube air at various pressures?

Tags: pressure, air, ionization-energy

From the minimum air pressure to the highest air pressure achievable with glow discharge tubes what is the degrees of ionization associated with them? 
What is the minimum degree of ionization of glow discharge plasma?

Comment: The degree of ionization in glow discharge tubes is usually quite low, on the order of 1 % or below.